# Set picture marker symbol for a layer with arcpy (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, symbology, arcgis-10.3

I have an ArcGIS map document with one layer symbolized with Categories > Unique values. I want to update symbology for this layer by specifying a path to a picture marker symbol for every unique value. I can do that manually by clicking each default symbol in the Layer properties > Symbology and then Edit Symbol > type = Picture Marker Symbol and browsing to the file needed.

I have a list of `attribute value -- name of .bmp file on disk`.

Is there a way to do this in an automated way with ArcGIS/arcpy?

Comment: I found this? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006n000000 ... I have used UniqueValueRenderers in Javascript, but not sure about ArcPy ...

Comment: @JasonBK, unfortunately, this tool requires having a .lyr file with the symbology pre-set. In my case, I am looking for a way to create such a .lyr file programmatically.

Comment: could you create a layer first using http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000070000000 ?

Comment: Yes I could. However there is no meaning to do that because I need to set symbols for every category in my layer first. And my question is about doing that in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is not (yet?) possible. See [ArcGIS 10.2 documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/UniqueValuesSymbology/00s30000005s000000/):

> For access to the complete set of layer symbology properties and settings, for example, changing individual symbols for individual classes, it is necessary to author these changes in the ArcMap user interface and then save those changes to a layer file. These custom settings can then be applied to existing layers using the UpdateLayer function.