# Set picture marker symbol for a layer with arcpy - ArcGIS Pro 2.2.4 & ArcGIS 10.6

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, arcgis-pro

A little UP about the question in the title. I found yet this question on a topic : [Set picture marker symbol for a layer with arcpy (ArcGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144680/set-picture-marker-symbol-for-a-layer-with-arcpy-arcgis?answertab=active&newreg=1c78bf7b593f4a98b94e4c913b2aaff1)

And my question is the same.

My purpose is about how to batch import many picture to picture marker symbol on .style file. The batch should work on ArcPY as possible.

I know that .style could be considered as a .mdb file. I opened previous .style I created on ArcCatalog to watch the file structure.

Is it a right to considered to import the pictures as on a database with ArcPy.

And how scripting this one ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set picture marker symbol for a layer with arcpy (ArcGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144680/set-picture-marker-symbol-for-a-layer-with-arcpy-arcgis)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my answer is the same of Alex Tereshenkov. Can we produce with Python code a symbology from symbols images (.EMF or .PNG) in a shape ?